# Не работает @requestBody

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jackson

Здравствуйте.  В моем проекте на spring у меня не получается получить данные в в аргументе @RequestBody. 
вот контроллер:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "submit" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestBody RequestData requestData) {
    System.out.println(requestData.getPeriod());
    return "что-то там";
}
```

js

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "<c:url value="/submit" />",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                period: $("input[name='PERIOD']").val()
            })
        });
```

вот так выглядит json который отправляется на сервер:

```
{"period":"2016/07/08 21:04"}
```

вот так выглядит сам объект:

```
@Data
public class RequestData{       
    private String period;
}
```

К проекту подключена библиотека   **jackson-databind-2.8.4**

От сервера приходит такой ответ : статус 415 , описание
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Подскажите пожалуйста , в связи с чем это может происходить?

Comment: У `class RequestData` есть методы гет/сет и пустой конструктор?

Comment: да, это библиотека Lombok , позволяет не писать гетеры и сеттеры, если проставить аyнотацию @Data

Comment: добавьте в ajax запрос параметр `dataType: "json"`

Comment: нет, не помогло

Comment: написано про 415 ошибку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/678086/182273