# 406 Spring MVC Json - не могу вернуть объект

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, rest

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу вернуть объект в REST-Controller (метод addUser). Вылазит ошибка HTTP Status 406 -The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Необходимо вернуть в виде:

{ 
"id": "Id generated by the back-end",
"firstName": "Some first name",
"lastName": "The last name",
"userName": "The user name"
 }

Буду благодарен за помощь!

```
Conntroller class



    @Controller
public class UserControllerImpl implements UserController {

    private UserRepository repository;

    public UserControllerImpl() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserControllerImpl(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeFile() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "userservice/addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=text/html")
    @Override
    public String addUser(ModelMap model) {
        return "userservice/addUser";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "userservice/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Override
    public @ResponseBody User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User user1 = this.repository.createUser(user);
        return user1;
    }
}
```

addUser.jsp

```js
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add User</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#register").submit(function (e) {
            var user = {
                firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
                lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
                userName: $("#userName").val(),
                plainTextPassword: $("#plainTextPassword").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                url: "addUser",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert('A user with the given username already exists fwefwefewfewf' + status + ". " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    
//    function funcSuccess(data) {
//        $("#id").text(data.id);
//        $("#firstName").text(data.firstName);
//        $("#lastName").text(data.lastName);
//        $("#userName").text(data.userName);
//    }
</script>

<form method="post" id="register" action="addUser" commandName="user">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="plainTextPassword" id="plainTextPassword" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="registerUserSubmit" value="Registration"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.temaprof.app.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Результат выполнения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия кнопки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.jsp

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Manager</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>User Manager</h1>
</div>
<a href="userservice/addUser">Registration</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>CRUD</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRUD</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Simple REST by temaprof</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!--DB-->
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1211</postgresql.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--DataBase-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

despatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.temaprof.app.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61642/discussion-on-question-by-artem-vorov-406-spring-mvc-json----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убери 
`consumes = {"application/json"}` у GET метода `addUser`. Какое отношение json имеет к этому методу?
Вместо этого использу `headers="Accept=text/html"`.

Если класс помечен аннотацией `@RestController`, то все методы яляются `@ResponseBody` и не могут возвращать JSP страницы.

Чтобы использовать аннтотации `@RequestBody`/`@ResponseBody` [нужно добавить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977973/whats-the-difference-between-mvcannotation-driven-and-contextannotation#comment4256810_3978283) тег `<mvc:annotation-driven />` в `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. Если не добавить тег, то это может вызывать HTTP ошибку `415 Unsupported Media Type`

> The server refused this request because the request entity
>   is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
>   requested method

Лог tomcat

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerEx‌​ceptionResolver.logE‌​xception
>   Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type
>   'application/json' not supported

---

Событие submit относится к форме, а не кнопке.

Чтобы использовать библиотеку jQuery (`$()`), ее нужно сначала подключить –  [Как подключить jQuery к проекту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/54806/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jquery-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83) .